# Wait until at least n elements present in selenium-python

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

I want to parse a list of records from webpage. The problem is that the records load through AJAX calls and are shown not simultaneously.

In order to archieve "wait till some record loads", I'm trying to use:

```
items = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.editablesection')
)
```

But it check only the presence of first `.editablesection`, not presence of all of them.

I tried to use `.editablesection:nth-of-type({item_ind})`, but my selector is a bit more complicated than that, and I think it's not really possible to use `:nth-of-type()` here.

At the time of check I have `item_ind` variable that contains index of `.editablesection` which I'm interested in now. Can I somehow specify a number of elements to wait in `check_presence()`?

Comment: What is your selector? How does it complecated?

Comment: `#requisitionListInterface tr.ftlrow td:nth-child(2) div.editablesection:nth-of-type({item_ind})`

I haven't managed to make it work.

Comment: what error do you get when run?

Comment: It simply doesn't find anything on the page, where there is something to find. 

Selector is correct to you, isn't it? Maybe I'm doing something wrong with Selenium itself.